# How to allow Upload Images to Imgur in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, upload, redux, axios, imgur

I wish to make use of Imgur to allow my users to upload images. I am currently using Firebase to store my database so I wish to fetch the image url and store in my database (.jpg) then render the image using the url. I thought of using axios to make async request to the Imgur API but I am not sure how to start.

It just seem so impossible to allow the users to upload conveniently and then return the url with redux-form.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible at all, you can use Axios or Fetch for upload and api calls, if you want Redux use it in conjunction with redux-saga and you are done!

Comment: do you mind showing an example? I am a little confused. How do you return the url link to Field component of redux-form then?

Comment: "action -> redux-saga -> reducer -> redux state -> field value" so you need to read documentation about redux actions, redux-saga usage for async calls, redux reducers.